# how to append nested li from JSON using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I want to bring the json data to front end like in the picture.
How do i do it, here is my code. I want it nested like in the pic below.

This is how far i got with my code.

HTML:

```
 </body>
   <div id="active"></div>
 </body>
```

JQuery

```
<script>
   $.getJSON("active.json", function(result){
   $.each(result, function(i, field){
   var UniqueNames= $.unique(result.map(function (d) {
   return d.gpanel;
   }));
   $("#active").append('<li>'+UniqueNames[i]+'</li>');
   });
   });
</script>
```

JSON:

```
  [{"ID":"1","gpanel":"sfd","ptitle":"sdffd","panel":"1,2",
  "free":"yes","fees":"0.00"},
  {"ID":"2","gpanel":"sdfd","ptitle":"sdfds","panel":"1",
  "free":"yes","fees":"0.00"},
   {"ID":"3","gpanel":"sdf","ptitle":"sdf","panel":"1",
  "free":"yes","fees":"0.00"},
   {"ID":"4","gpanel":"sfd","ptitle":"fes","panel":"1",
  "free":"yes","fees":"0.00"},
  {"ID":"5","gpanel":"bbbfff","ptitle":"hgffg","panel":"1,2",
  "free":"yes","fees":"0.00"}
  ]
```

thanks in advance.
[image]

Comment: not sure if this is the full solution but the $("#active").html('<li>'+UniqueNames+'</li>'); line... your overwriting the html over and over again, try and use .append instead of .html

Comment: i got it working with $("#active").append($('<li/>').html(UniqueNames[i])); but the issue is i need to append nested <ul>'s like in the pic.

Comment: you need to create nested ul structure to get result as the image. But how are u differentiating the level(i.e Reduced Fee was displaying in 2nd level)?

Comment: Reduced fee is the checkbox values, in the json it is displayed as (1,2,3). i.e 1 for regular, 2 for reduced fee and 3 for limited assurance. it varies with user input , i.e if the user choose just 2 and 3 then reduced fee would be on the top.

Comment: ok fine but what about the change1,Test,test 1234. where this data available?

Comment: change1 is from "ptitle" . 'ptitile' is set based on the checkbox values clicked. if 1,2,3 are clicked then change1 is set for 1,2, and 3. which is regular, reduced fee , and limited assurance.

Comment: ok, so you need final display like `gpanel -> panel -> ptitle`, right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138940/discussion-between-wisely-d-cruizer-and-vara-prasad).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution 1**

You can try this code

```
$.getJSON("active.json", function(result){
  var UniqueNames= $.unique(result.map(function (d) {
    return d.gpanel;
  }));
  var ul_block = $("<ul/>");
  $.each(UniqueNames, function(i) {
    $(ul_block).append('<li>' + UniqueNames[i] + '</li>');
  });
  $("#active").append(ul_block);
});
```

I have made some changes in your code,

1) code which is used for fetching uniquenames was removed inside from loop, so that it will not process everytime even though you required once

2) changed the loop from `result` to `UniqueNames`, since you are displaying those names only

You can made changes in my code to get required output i.e level of display

**Solution 2:**

As per the data structure and conditions you provided, Please check this code

```
$.getJSON("active.json", function(result) {
    var panel_arr = ["", "Regular", "Reduced Fee", "Limited Assurance"];
    var ul_block = $("<ul/>");
    $.each(result, function(i, data) {
        console.log(data);
        var panels = data.panel.split(",");
        var uli_block = $("<ul/>");
        $.each(panels, function(j, jdata){
            var ulii_block = $("<ul/>");
            $(ulii_block).append($("<li/>").text(data.ptitle));
            $(uli_block).append($("<li/>").text(panel_arr[panels[j]])).append(ulii_block);
        });
        $(ul_block).append($("<li/>").text(data.gpanel).append(uli_block));
    });
    $("#active").append(ul_block);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this. But my question is how would i create a nested list? Thats what im curious to know. We just got to the '<ul>' now , i wanna know how i would place the '<li>' s inside the <ul> tags. In return forming a nested list.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. i was getting hectic over jquery each loop. I still have to study your code though. Thanks for guiding me.